# Setting priority for a sql read/write?

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm doing this in vb.net, but if there's a non-managed solution I'm open to that as well. I have a Windows Mobile 6.5 application that stores local data in a sql server compact database on some flash memory, with moderate read/write times. The issue is, I have a background thread that sometimes does large read/writes from the database and can slow down my main thread's operations. Is there a way I can set the priority so that my main thread's read/writes are done first? I wouldn't think changing the thread priority would have any effect, I'm looking for more like I/O priority..

Comment: Set the thread priority, normally that is how I would do it for example with File IO (but typically I would want the file IO to have higher priority than compute-bound operations). However, if it is your database getting slowed down then it may not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a flush of the write buffer by using a SqlCeTransactiona and setting CommitMode.Immediate - more info on my blog here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/05/sql-server-compact-code-snippet-of-week_21.html